# Formtastic Gems input check_boxes didn't support checked/selected list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic, activeadmin

Am using formtastics in Active Admin gem Everything is working find except one thing that am passing it list to be checked/selected on check boxes list but not working.. So kindly help me in this regard. Thanks..

I tried this in Simple form Its working fine over there but not in Formtastic.

```
<%= f.input :surgery_type_procedures, :label=>false,:as=>:check_boxes,:required=>false,:collection => st.surgery_type_procedures.all.collect!{ |p| [p.to_s, p.id] },:checked=>@surgery_type_procedures %>

<%= f.input :surgery_type_procedures, :label=>false,:as=>:check_boxes,:required=>false,:collection => st.surgery_type_procedures.all.collect!{ |p| [p.to_s, p.id] },:selected=>@surgery_type_procedures %>
```

Didn't Select Any check_box out which are in "@surgery_type_procedures" so kindly tell me is  formtastic support checked or uncheck option??/

Comment: what is your real problem ? What you have ?

Comment: Now i have updated Question Hope now u understand my problem..

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.input :column_name, :input_html => {:checked => 'checked'} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `p.id` to `p.id.to_s` and remove `checked`/`selected` key. It should be works.